# Use of 'The' at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: definite-article

1. The payment was made today
2. Payment was made today

In which context, the above can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Is the question "*which payment?*" important?

If yes, use the article.  You're expecting the listener/reader to know which payment.  If you don't think the listener/reader will assume correctly you will have to add more words to the sentence.

If not, no article needed or you can use the indefinite article.